# Infamous admin login redirect

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, login, directory, domain-mapping

I have a multisite installed with the domain mapping plugin.

All the domains work fine, except...

One of the sites is on a subdirectory (the main site running Magento).

I added a symlink to the original installation directory in the WP subdirectory (`/wp/` in my case) because I needed to change the `.htaccess` file for a different rewrite base.
The issue is that the `wp-admin` does not work. Upon login, the page refreshes (with `redirect_to=` in the URL) and then nothing happenes.
Upon further research, I've noticed that the cookie the site tries to set is for the parent site domain...

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the constant `COOKIE_DOMAIN` to an empty value or the value of the real address.

Example:

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '' );
```

Be aware WordPress has a lot of issues with symlinks, so there might be other problems too.

Comment: Tried that....didn't help

Comment: I got the admin to work (no idea how...) but now the actual site pages redirect to /wp/wp/  from regular /wp/ . any ideas?

Comment: @boruch That’s a new question. Try to get a [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog).

Comment: @toscno +1 , it is not a mod_rewrite thing. I removed the htaccess file, and still getting the redirect. it seems like a WP thing

Comment: @boruch [Look here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=Invalid%20redirect%20without%20mod_rewrite&tags=redirect,urls,url-rewriting).